# jQuery : Trigger something when a textbox is cleared

Tags: jquery, textbox, onchange

I have few textboxes on a screen and they are all disabled except the first one. When starting to enter something in the first 1 the second needs to enable and so on. I did this easily with the following:

```
$(savn1).keypress(function() {
$(savn2).find('input').attr("disabled",false);
});
```

The problem comes when you clear the input from the first box - the second doesn't disable which should be the case. I reworked my code into the following:

```
$(savn1).change( function() {

var strSavn1 = fnAnswer_getTextbox('savn1');

if(strSavn1!==''){
  $(savn2).find('input').attr("disabled",false);
}else{
  $(savn2).find('input').attr("disabled",true);
}
});
```

Now this is exactly what I need except in order for this to take effect after you type something you need to click somewhere for the change to take effect.

I need this happening dynamically - type/enable, clear/disable.

Can you please advise?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try keyup event, it should trigger on clearing input also.

```
$(savn1).keyup (function() {
  // check value to enable or disable second input
});
```